# twilio get conference participants from friendly name in php

Tags: php, twilio

I'm developing a PHP application in Twilio that makes use of their conference feature, and despite a lot of searching, I'm stuck on the following:

Somewhere I start a conference using TwiML:

`<Dial>`
`<Conference>MyConference</Conference>`
`</Dial>`

and other people join it using the same markup. This all works fine. Then elsewhere in the application, I want to determine how many participants there are in the conference, while it is still going on. I can see that these docs:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant

should provide the answer, but how do I access the conference using only the friendly name I have given it above? Specifically I want to know how many conference participants there are, using PHP and the REST API.

I hope that makes sense, and thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Contact your twilio rep and get their techs on it... have always found them responsive to such questions.  Appears to be a gap in the documentation how to query the friendly name from your account list and get the SID which would be required to get the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You'll need to use the REST API to first grab the conference SID.  One of the parameters that you can pass into the API is named FriendlyName, so you can use that to get the specific conference you're trying to count the participants in:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference#list

Using the PHP helper library this is going to looking something like:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '123');
foreach ($client->account->conferences->getIterator(0, 50, array(
  'FriendlyName' => 'yourConf'
)) as $conf) {
  print $conf->sid;
}
```

Once you have the Conference SID then you can use the API again to get the number of Participants in that specific Conference:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#list

Making a request to the Participant subresource will give you a list of all the participants in that specific conference call.  Using that you can get the count from the enumerable list.  Again, using the PHP helper it will look something like this:

```
$conference = $client->account->conferences->get($sid);
$page = $conference->participants->getPage(0, 50);
$participants = $page->participants;
$participantCount = count($participants);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what i was looking for! the first step was the bit i was struggling to work out from the twilio docs.

Comment: FYI, in the end I needed to add the condition 'Status' => 'in-progress' to 'FriendlyName' => 'yourConf' to get it to find the participants of the current conference.

Comment: Can we get conference participants after conference end ?